# Execute stored procedure in another server from sql agent job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, remote, sql-server-agent

I am trying execute stored procedure in remote server in sql agent job using sqlserver 2008 r2

```
  select * from openquery([1.1.1.1],'exec [DB_Name].[dbo].[sp_ProcName]')
```

Or

```
EXEC [1.1.1.1].[DB_Name].[dbo].[sp_ProcName]
```

but I got the folowing error:

Could not find server '1.1.1.1' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

(I type the correct IP)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As the error message suggests, `OPENQUERY` looks for a linked server.  If you don't have that set up, and don't have the rights to get that set up, then perhaps using an [`OPENROWSET`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) query might be the way to go.  This will allow you to connect to a datasource on a more ad-hoc basis, by writing a query which contains a full connection string.

In your case, you may get the results by using something like:

```
SELECT spresults.* 
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=1.1.1.1;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
                'EXEC [db_name].dbo.[sp_ProcName]') AS spresults
```

CAVEAT:  This will fail at runtime if your SP returns multiple resultsets.

CAVEAT 2: This will also fail if Ad Hoc queries haven't been allowed.  To sort that out, you need to run the [appropriate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187569%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) [`sp_configure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189631%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) statement(s):

```
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
reconfigure
exec sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
reconfigure
```

Of course, in order to run `sp_configure`, you'll need the appropriate rights in SQL Server.  According to the "Permissions" section of the [`sp_configure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188787%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) documentation, that's "ALTER SETTINGS", which is by default part of the sysadmin and serveradmin roles, but may be assigned to other roles too.

Comment: I got the folowing error: SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server.

Comment: Yes, sorry, should have mentioned that.  Hang on.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - thanks for the "exec" edit.  Brain was definitely not in gear this morning!